# Find Fragmented Files

Tags: java, filesystems

I can't seem to find a way to detect fragmented files via Java. I'd assume the filesystem part would be abstracted and made easy via Java, but can't seem to get any results from Google.

Please advise on how to read low-level file system data via Java specifically for finding and fixing fragmented files.

Comment: It probably depends very heavily on the file system being used, as many of them handle file fragmentation very differently.  You'd need to find a pretty low-level system API for something like this.  In general, the file system's job is to abstract this information from applications.

Comment: Why all the close votes? It's a specific question, no? Thanks @David, do you have any recommendations for such a library?

Comment: do you just want to know if a file is fragmented and by how many bytes or more information on the fragments?

Comment: I'd like to know if a file is fragmented, and by how much (in bytes). I can work out how to fix it later I suppose.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181074/why-close-find-fragmented-files discssuion on why this was closed @SnakeDoc

Comment: Java is a fairly high-level language, and some of its abstraction is done for safety reasons.  I suspect that it doesn't provide this kind of low-level access.  [This program](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/defragment-hard-disk-faster-with-java-defrag/) appears to be capable of doing it, but it calls low-level Windows API's to accomplish it.

Comment: @tgkprog thanks for going to bat for me. I (as you suspected) was not looking for a "here's some code" answer... but instead provided some links to reading material or a link to a library that may help me do what I want. Thanks again, your info below has been helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to design a program that is in Java but calls Java Native Interfaces or my preference - custom processes to do the actual work outside of Java. So any solution would be in part OS dependent. Though some solutions would work on more than one OS like the linux/ unix flavours.

For example on windows can use http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897428.aspx Call it from a java program (spawn an external process - using ProcessBuilder)

I used it on my box, it does not work 100% of the time, so you might even have to have a multi strategy - use method 1, call it within a try-catch so if it has an error you can try method 2 ...

On my windows laptop called process with parameters:

```
 c:/apps/win/sysinternals/Contig.exe -a -v D:/u/a.jpg
```

**Output**

> Contig v1.7 - Makes files contiguous Copyright (C) 1998-2012 Mark
>   Russinovich Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com
>
> ------------------------ Processing D:\u\a.jpg Scanning file...
>
> [Cluster] Runlength   [0] 2
>
> File size: 5603 bytes D:\u\a.jpg is in 1 fragment
>   ------------------------ Summary:
>        Number of files processed   : 1
>        Average fragmentation       : 1 frags/file

Parse this out and you have part of your answer. you will have to get in to each OS API to get more details of fragmentation. Open source de-fragmentation code would be a good place to start. They have what you want plus the extra step of actually de-fragmenting which you can suppress.

Comment: great answer to get me going in the right direction. Thank you for taking the time to answer this, and battle it out for me in Meta. +1

Comment: another architecture might be to make a socket server in c/c++ code that does the defrag mode, and also listens for requests from the Java process. Advantage: less time if your processing 1,000s of files do not have to start multiple processes, so a little less over head. Disadvantage : need to do the extra coding in c/ c++ and see how to make it cross platform.

Comment: I didn't think of that... this may be the way to go for a true platform agnostic approach (at least in theory). I'll give it a go. Thanks!